# Creating java File with unlimited number of lines

Tags: java, file, max, line

I am writing to file using java and I am writing more than 47678 lines. the maximum number of lines in the file is 47678. I am wondering if I can extend the number of the lines or what should I do. I am creating the file using File and I am writing using FileWriter

Comment: You should post code that shows what you are doing. It's good that you found a helpful answer below, but questions should be descriptive about what you tried, what you expected, and what happened, along with including code and actual output. This has good info: [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with it e.g. the following program will write 65535 lines in the file:

```
import java.io.*;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
        for(int i=0;i<65535;i++)
            writer.write("Happy Diwali!\n");         
        writer.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: FileWriter did not do the job but BufferedWriter did exactly what is expected thanks @Arvind Kumar Avinash

Comment: You should use _try-with-resources_ to avoid having to call `close()` manually.